# EKEventViewController doesn't appear Edit Button

Tags: calendar, swift2, ekevent

I have EKEvents in table view, when I select one App should present EKEventViewController and allow the user to edit the EKEvnt.

The problem is: the EKEventViewController appeared but the Edit button doesn't!

I have an old App on Objective C use same method, i tried to run it on same Xcode I work on (7.1.1) it worked!

This is the code:

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {

    let editController = EKEventViewController(nibName: nil, bundle: nil)
    editController.event = eventsTable[indexPath.row]

    // Allow event editing.
    editController.allowsEditing = true
    editController.delegate = self as EKEventViewDelegate
    self.navigationController?.pushViewController(editController, animated: true)
    self.navigationController?.navigationBar.hidden = false
}
```

[image]